# Functions that takes 3 Strings, where the first is part of the 3rd , and changes the 1st string in the 3rd with the second string

Tags: haskell

I need to write a Haskell function, which takes 3 strings as input, where the 1st string is part of the 3rd string and substitutes the first string with the second one.

I've tried using recursion for that, but it seems that I didn't set my base cases properly and also receive" signature  lacks accompanying binding error" ( I am completely new to Haskell)

```
change:: String -> String -> String -> String
change [] [] [] = []
change [] ys zs = ys
change xs [] zs = zs
change xs ys [] = []
change (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) =  change xs ys zs
```

code here

The function output should be for example:
change "Hello" "Goodbye" "Hello class" 
"Goodbye Class"

Comment: The “signature lacks accompanying binding” isn't in the code you posted. Always make sure you post a [MCVE]. Also, your attempt could use a bit more explanation of how you intended to solve the problem with it. Right now it barely does _anything_ related to the task.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at the [subIndex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.2.1/docs/Data-List-Utils.html#v:subIndex) library function.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the `replace :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Text` function of the `Data.Text`.

First add this pragma `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`, you can read about it here https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overloaded-string-literals

Then the change function would be like this :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text ( pack, unpack, replace)

change :: String -> String -> String -> String
change xs ys = unpack . replace (pack xs) (pack ys) . pack
```

As you can see i'm using `pack` and `unpack` to switch `Text` and `String`
Please see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text.html if you want to understand more `Data.Text`

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Haskell.As I think, the code you have written has no error.But It does not gives the desired result as you want. Basically it gives a output string depending on the length of the shorter string.As for your example, the output is "ye class".

This program work for desired result,

```
change :: String -> String -> String -> String
change _  _    ""   =  ""

change l1 l2 (z:zs) = if l1 == take (length l1) (z:zs) then l2 ++ drop (length l1) (z:zs) else z:(change l1 l2 zs)
```